# An exception occurred: Illegal string offset 'type' in C:\wamp64\www\library\EWRdiscord\Model\Discord.php on line 65

Tags: php

**Error Lines below**

> XenForo_Application::handlePhpError() in EWRdiscord/Model/Discord.php at line 65
>   EWRdiscord_Model_Discord->getChannels() in EWRdiscord/Option/Channels.php at line 9
>   EWRdiscord_Option_Channels::renderOption()
>   call_user_func() in XenForo/ViewAdmin/Helper/Option.php at line 345
>   XenForo_ViewAdmin_Helper_Option::_renderCallbackOptionHtml() in XenForo/ViewAdmin/Helper/Option.php at line 72
>   XenForo_ViewAdmin_Helper_Option::renderPreparedOptionHtml() in XenForo/ViewAdmin/Helper/Option.php at line 33
>   XenForo_ViewAdmin_Helper_Option::renderPreparedOptionsHtml() in XenForo/ViewAdmin/Option/ListOptions.php at line 30
>   XenForo_ViewAdmin_Option_ListOptions->renderHtml() in XenForo/ViewRenderer/Abstract.php at line 227
>   XenForo_ViewRenderer_Abstract->renderViewObject() in XenForo/ViewRenderer/HtmlAdmin.php at line 78
>   XenForo_ViewRenderer_HtmlAdmin->renderView() in XenForo/FrontController.php at line 607
>   XenForo_FrontController->renderView() in XenForo/FrontController.php at line 158
>   XenForo_FrontController->run() in C:/wamp64/www/admin.php at line 13

**Line 65 below**

```
            if ($channel['type'] != 'text')
```

**Small Slice of code.**

```
    public function getChannels($voice = false)
{
    $channels = $this->getGuild('/channels');

    if (!empty($channels))
    {
        if (!$voice)
        {
            foreach ($channels AS $key => &$channel)
            {
                if ($channel['type'] != 'text')
                {
                    unset($channels[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        usort($channels, create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a["position"] - $b["position"];'));
    }

    return $channels;
}
```

Comment: do a print_r($channel) to make sure that the array has a key called 'type'.

Comment: Where am I placing that? @victor

Comment: This isn't a duplicate it's Discord intergration with XenForo and the errors are killing me.  @ AbraCadaver

Comment: put it right before your if statement.  if ($channel['type'] != 'text')